# Limit of $ \epsilon^2 w \ln \epsilon$ with $w$ an constant

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits

let $w$ an constant. If $\epsilon^2 w \to 0$ when $\epsilon \to 0$, there is an possibility to have $\epsilon^2 w \ln \epsilon \to \beta <0$?
Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}( \epsilon^2\ln \epsilon)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\frac{\ln \epsilon}{\epsilon^{-2}} \right)$$

now use L'Hopital:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\frac{\ln \epsilon}{\epsilon^{-2}} \right)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\frac{\epsilon^{-1}}{-2\epsilon^{-3}} \right)=0$$

and then

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}(\epsilon^2w\ln \epsilon)=w\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}( \epsilon^2\ln \epsilon)=0$$

and the answer for your question is **NO**.

Comment: Than you so much for the answer

Comment: @jiji: you are very welcome!